# Message specification for encrypted content

Tags: .net, cryptography, .net-core, specifications

1. What **standard for cryptographically protected messages** does the .NET Framework (and .NET Core) supports?
2. And which are recommended for **authenticated encryption with Elliptic Curve Cryptography** and for data at rest.

I stumbled upon the **Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)** and now I'm curious about different approaches. Which I can easily adapt because they are part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Is this data at rest of in transit? What kind of data and general size?

Comment: I did extend the question with data at rest.

Comment: What do you mean with "with ECs"?

Comment: @Maarten Added Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Comment: What kind of protection do you need? Confidentiality? Integrity/authenticity? It seems Enveloped CMS support is there in .NET core, but no SignedCMS yet. I'm not sure that authenticated encryption is in there either [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14197). You may have to revert to a library such as Bouncy Castle.